# Error pushing from BitBucket to CodeCommmit

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codecommit

I've set up a Bitbucket Pipeline to push to CodeCommit per Jay Proulx's instructions at https://medium.com/@jay_proulx/aws-codecommit-from-atlassian-bitbucket-and-bitbucket-pipelines-for-ci-offloading-4f1131695802

I've uploaded an ssh key (generated by puttygen on Windows) to AWS IAM and configured this in the Bitbucket Pipeline variables as below.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo $CodeCommitKey > ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.tmp
          - base64 -d ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa.tmp > ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
          - chmod 400 ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
          - echo $CodeCommitConfig > ~/.ssh/config.tmp
          - base64 -d  ~/.ssh/config.tmp > ~/.ssh/config
          - set +e
          - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $CodeCommitHost
          - set -e
          - git remote add codecommit ssh://$CodeCommitRepo
          - git push codecommit $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
```

$CodeCommitConfig is the base64 encoded version of:

```
   Host git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
        HostName git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
        User APKAxxxx
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/codecommit_rsa
```

Environment Variables in Bitbucket Pipeline:

```
$CodeCommitHost = git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
$CodeCommitRepo = git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo
$CodeCommitUser = APKAxxxx
$CodeCommitKey = [The base64 encoded version of the SSH private key]
```

At the last step of the pipeline, I get the error:

```
+ git push codecommit $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I get a similar error at an earlier step:

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $CodeCommitHost
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '103.8.175.33' to the list of known hosts.
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've been through the setup a few times and get the same results - what have I done wrong?

Comment: getting same error myself, did you fix this?

Comment: @edencorbin yep, answer below :)

Comment: interesting, I was running into this exact issue using ssh-keygen on linux, atm I am just going straight to CodeDeploy but I would like to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating keys with puttygen, use ssh-keygen from git bash.